# Looking for Bezier curve OpenGL open source implemention

Tags: opengl, open-source, curves

well in short im looking for something like this as open source.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cut3_A0Xm3Y

i need to implement especially the Bezier curve editing in my app in open gl .
any ideas where i can find such open source implementation ? ( can be c++ or java )

Comment: *"This video is not available."* How about a screenshot or description? Do you just want to draw a bezier curve or want to move the points etc.? Also keep in mind that this site is more about "I've written this, it's not working, why?" It's not meant as a loose collection of links or suggestions/recommendations.

Comment: the video does show on my browser .. 
i know what this site about , the problem is i dont have any starting point , i want to able to draw Bezier curve with handlers to change its curve .

Comment: You want to know how to draw a bezier curve or how to make an interactive graphic editor? Those should be two (or more) separate questions as making an editor is quite a complex task.

Comment: draw a bezier curve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw a bezier curve using OpenGL or Direct3D you need to sub-divide the bezier into line segments. If you do this with enough sub-divisions it will look like a smooth curve.

Interpolation functions:

```
vec2 Lerp(vec2 a, vec2 b, float i) {
    return a + (b - a) * i;
}

vec2 Bezier4(vec2 a, vec2 b, vec2 c, vec2 d, float i) {
    return Lerp(Lerp(a, b, i), Lerp(c, d, i), i);
}
```

Then you generate a series of points on the bezier curve and draw connected lines between them:

```
vec2 bezier[4] = { bezier control points };

int resolution = 8;
vec2 points[resolution];

for(int n=0; n < resolution; ++n){
    float i = (float)n / (float)(resolution-1);

    points[n] = Bezier4(bezier[0], bezier[1] bezier[2] bezier[3], i);
}

DrawConnectLines(points, resolution);
```

You can increase the resolution to make the curve approximation smoother.